# Run svn command on VisualSVN Server

Tags: svn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

Ahoi!

here is what i wanna achive: I've got a huge SVN Repository. Because the Checkout would take like forever and a few hundred GB i was wondering if i can execute a SVN Command on the console where the VisualSVN Server is running to determine any svn:externals with absolute paths via `svn propget svn:externals -R` command.

So far the repository doesn't seem the be accessible w/o checking it out. Am i right (i hope not)? Or is there another way to achive what im looking for?

Thanks!
Timo

Comment: Can you reword your question. It's not really clear what you want. Are you always checking out at the root of your repository? By the way, you can do a `svn plist -R` on a URL instead of a checked out directory.

Comment: I want to get a list of all externals used in the repository. So far i havent found a way without checking it out completely which takes really long considering the size and my connection. I'll look into plist -r. Thanks

Comment: I've figured it out. The svn propget is executable on a repository without checking it out. I just didnt knew that you can pass the repository path as a parameter for propget. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to get a list of all externals used in the repository. So far i havent found a way without checking it out completely which takes really long considering the size and my connection.

That's easier to understand. Try this:

```
$ svn pget -Rv svn:externals http://svn.vegibank.com/svn
```

You don't need the `-v`. It changes the output to a three line output that's easier to read.

#### Without `-v`

```
http://svn.vegibank.com/svn/project - utils http://svn.vegibank.com/svn/utils
```

#### With `-v`

```
Properties on 'http://svn.vegibank.com/svn/project'
  svn:externals
     utils  http://svn.vegibank.com/svn/utils
```

However, you might prefer the one line format because it's easier to parse. Simply remove everything after the "`-`" and you have a list of directories with the property.

This command will take a long time to run, so, run the command, and get some coffee. Or, maybe get lunch. Or maybe dinner, and a Broadway show. At least you don't need to checkout the entire repository which would require several gigabytes of disk space.